# Problema com o windows, não reconhece outra Memória RAM

Tags: windows

Estava com o windows travando tudo quanto é tipo de programa, então adiquiri uma **Memória RAM** de 
***2GB*** sendo que a minha instalada também é de ***2GB***.

Então certo dia fui ao Painel de Controle e reparei a seguinte coisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dizendo que havia 4GB de memória RAM instalada mas só **2GB** era utilizavel. O que eu faço para consertar isto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Windows com 32-bits tem capacidade de memória RAM limitada, portanto mesmo adquirindo mais memória, o sistema operacional não reconhece devido a limitação. O limite do sistema de 32 bits é 4GB. Na verdade, é a quantidade máxima de memória que o sistema consegue endereçar (2^32 endereços == 4GB). No entanto, parte desta memória é reservada para evitar problemas na performance e na utilização por ausência de memória para processamento.

Como sugestão, atualize a versão do Windows para 64-bits.

Fonte: http://blogs.technet.com/b/suporte/archive/2010/04/16/limites-de-memoria-32-bits-vs-64-bits.aspx

Comment: Se eu fosse instalar Windows 7 64-bits como eu poderia saber se o processador suporta ou não?

Comment: Nathan, você deve verificar os requisitos técnicos do processador antes de proceder com o upgrade. Procure no site do frabricante do processador se é possível a utilização.

Comment: O limite do sistema de 32 bits é 4GB. Na verdade, é a quantidade máxima de memória que o sistema consegue endereçar (2^32 endereços == 4GB).

Comment: Acrescentarei o comentário do Beterraba à resposta. No entanto, o Sistema Operacional não utiliza os 4 GB completo, pois guarda parte dessa quantidade para uma "reserva", evitando que o sistema deixe de funcionar por utilização em excesso.